# R 3.1.0 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length error

Tags: r, for-loop

I have written the following R code:

```
csv_data<-temp[1:3]

req_data<-NULL

for(j in 1:length(1:3)){
  req_data[j]<-read.table(csv_data,sep=",")
}
```

csv_data contains 3 files "001.csv", "002.csv" and "003.csv"

each file has 4 columns

After this for loop I expect req_data to contain the 3 files as:

```
req_data[1] - contains "001.csv" (all 4 columns)
req_data[2] - contains "002.csv" (all 4 columns)
req_data[3] - contains "003.csv" (all 4 columns)
```

But what req_data actually contains:

```
req_data[1] - contains "001.csv" (only 1st column)
req_data[2] - contains "002.csv" (only 1st column)
req_data[3] - contains "003.csv" (only 1st column)
```

How can i get the expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that your program works as is without giving 3 warnings. Since read.table returns a data.frame, you can make a self-contained example als follows.

```
req_data<-NULL

for(j in 1:length(1:3)){
  req_data[j]<- iris[sample(nrow(iris),10),]
}
```

Giving: 
Warning messages:
1: In req_data[j] <- iris[sample(nrow(iris), 10), ] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

When you write:

```
req_data[[j]] <-...
```

you are adding the dataframe as elements to a list, which should work as required. You probable need some do.call(rbind- magic afterward, but that was not part of the question.

Comment: Yes that req_data[[j]]<-... solved the problem. Thanx